# Python TA-Lib not working with pandas series

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use the TA-Lib in python on Ubuntu 12.04 as [described in the official documentation](http://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/). However, when using pandas `DataFrame`s or `Series`, as shown in multiple examples on different sources, I get the following `TypeError`:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test1.py", line 14, in
>   
>       analysis['rsi'] = ta.RSI(spy.Close) TypeError: Argument 'real' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Series)

When executing e.g. this code:

```
import pandas.io.data as data
import pandas as pd
import talib as ta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Download SP500 data with pandas
spyidx = data.get_data_yahoo('SPY', '2013-01-01')
analysis = pd.DataFrame(index = spyidx.index)
analysis['rsi'] = ta.RSI(spyidx.Close)
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 6):

For `pandas` >= 0.13.0:

> Passing a Series directly to a cython function expecting an ndarray
>   type will no long work directly, you must pass Series.values

So before `TA-lib` revises its API to accommodate the newer `pandas` versions, you need to use `Series.values` or `DataFrame.values`.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to use abstract functions:

`import talib.abstract as ta`

instead of

`import talib as ta`

Second make sure you use correct names:

```
ta_serie = pd.DataFrame({
    'high': _1_minute_tf.max_price,
    'open': _1_minute_tf.open_price,
    'close': _1_minute_tf.close_price,
    'low': _1_minute_tf.min_price
})
```

Finally, enjoy:`ta.SAR(ta_serie, window)` will give you what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
analysis = pd.DataFrame(index = spyidx.index.values)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates, TA-lib expects numpy.ndarray, but spyidx.Close is Pandas series

Change this line

```
 analysis['rsi'] = ta.RSI(spyidx.Close)
```

to :

```
 analysis['rsi'] = ta.RSI(np.array(spyidx.Close))
```